# _tkinter.TclError: can't find package Tktable

Tags: python, tkinter, tktable

I wanted to run this program posted here http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTableCalendar, but to run this I need the `tktable` wrapper https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTableWrapper, but the wrapper throws an error

```
File "tktable.py", line 115, in __init__
master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'Tktable')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package Tktable
```

I don't understand why it is behaving this way. How to fix this problem?

Comment: If you happen to have debian or ubuntu, `apt-get install tk-table` might work.

Comment: No, I'm using windows 10 and I need to solve this for windows as I am making a GUI for windows. But I will try using it in ubuntu.

Comment: In case of windows you may have to build [Tktable.dll](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/)  yourself

Comment: @j.j. hakala after doing what you suggested, it seems to work on Ubuntu, thanks.

Comment: But I don't have any idea how to build the dll. I checked that link before but couldn't figure out much also I downloaded the tktable folder but couldn't configure/make

Comment: Because : Maybe you use `Python3.x`. Check `TkTableWrapper.py` line 35 is `import Tkinter` not `import tkinter`. Throw core error not additional module error ! Use this for both version. https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/master/arelle/TkTableWrapper.py AND if have't `tktable` install this https://github.com/dossan/tktable

Comment: No im using python 2.7 and I have already checked  and used both github file you provided, no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching for a long time I found this

> http://blog.clintecker.com/post/148453368/tktable-for-tkinter-and-python

which solves my problem.

Now the `TkTableCalender.py` is running properly.

Comment: So the latest version did not have binaries available, but older version had.

Answer (score -1):

You should install tktable...
Go this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkintertable/1.1.2

Download it...
Extract file.
And open the folder which has been extracted.
Open command prompt in same folder and type this command:

> python setup.py install

Wait while it is being set up...
After doing it try again.

Comment: This doesn't help much, since the error message `_tkinter.TclError: can't find package Tktable` refers to Tk module named Tktable. tkintertable is some other Tk related widget.

Comment: I had already installed this package before posting the question, this doesn't work.